# I have a file named hastanelistesi.json.In this file, I want to access the "hastaneAdi" and display the select-option menu

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a file named hastanelistesi.json.In this file, I want to access the "hastaneAdi" and display the select-option menu.But I always get the error. I get the json file from mssql. However, I've had more than one query with node.js, so I applied this path.

```
 {
 "recordsets": [
 [{
    "hastaneAdi": "ACADEMİC HOSPİTAL"
  },
  {
    "hastaneAdi": "ACIBADEM BAKIRKÖY HASTANESİ"
  },
  {
    "hastaneAdi": "ACIBADEM KOZYATAĞI HASTANESİ"
  }
  ]
  }
  //index.js
  var fs = require("fs");
  var liste = [];
  var result;
  var rawdata = fs.readFileSync('data.json');
  var data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
  var grouped_data = data.recordsets.map(function (item) {
  return item.hastaneAdi;
  });
  console.log(grouped_data);
  //jade page
  td
  select#hastaneismi.custom-select(name='hastaneismi')
  option(selected='') Seçiniz....
  -for item in grouped_data
  option=item.hastaneAdi   
  td
  button.btn.btn-light(type='submit', value='submit')
  img(style='height: 24px ; width: 24px', src='/images/kaydet.svg') 
  //and error
  Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: maybe there is an extra square bracket...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your json data is in a file (for example, `data.json`) saved in the same script's folder:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// read data
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('data.json');  

// parse data
let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);  

// map data
let grouped_data = data.recordsets.map((item) => { return item.hastaneAdi; })

console.log( grouped_data );
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/StableHorribleWrapper

### UPDATE

Assuming you correctly pass `grouped_data` to jade template, this should work:

```
select#hastaneismi.custom-select(name='hastaneismi')
  option(selected='') Seçiniz....
  -for item in grouped_data
    option=item
```

Comment: @özkankara if your question is resolved please accept the answer

Comment: c:\Users\drozk\Desktop\telrehberdeneme\views\kayitduzenledoktor.jade:84 82| select#gorevliOlduguHastane.custom-select(name='gorevliOlduguHastane') 83| option(selected='') Seçiniz.... > 84| -for item in grouped_data 85| option=item.hastaneAdi 86| td 87| button.btn.btn-light(type='submit', value='submit') Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: td
                    select#hastaneismi.custom-select(name='hastaneismi')
                      option(selected='') Seçiniz....
                         -for item in grouped_data
                           option=item.hastaneAdi

Comment: I don't know if I've written it in the right place, but I get the error when I try it from within the jade file and use it as a global variable in index.js in the router.

Comment: Logic as it should be, but unfortunately did not work like this.

Comment: is error in the jade view, right? How do you pass `grouped_data` to the view?

Comment: Yes I don't pass data jade view in select option menü to json file

Comment: I have not any problem page route and data transfer single guery mssql

Comment: you have to pass `grouped_data` to the view (eg, if you are using expressjs: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)